# NumberOfSpanningTrees command not working correctly

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I am attempting to use the Combinatorica `NumberOfSpanningTrees` command for all `n-cycle` graphs from 3 to 30. I am trying to get a table form showing whether it is true or false that `n-cycle` graphs have `n` spanning trees. However Mathematica does not seem to recognize the command. Am I am pre-loading the Combinatorica packages correctly?

```
<< Combinatorica`
Table[{i, NumberOfSpanningTrees[CycleGraph[i]] == i}, {i, 3, 30}] // TableForm
```

The output I get is:

[image]

I have also tried loading Combinatorica using the `Needs["Combinatorica`"].

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Combinatorica` package is now considered obsolete and not compatible with Mathematica's built-in Graph theory functionality. The function `CycleGraph`, which you are using, is a built-in function and is not understood by the `Combinatorica` package. You have to replace `CycleGraph[i]` simply by `Cycle[i]`, which is the corresponding object in Combinatorica. You can confirm this that by looking at (for example) `CycleGraph[5]` and `ShowGraph[Cycle[5]]`:

```
GraphicsRow[{CycleGraph[5] , ShowGraph[Cycle[5]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Actually, the Combinatorica package still has a lot of functionality that has nothing equivalent in the Kernel (and it is not clear if this will ever change completely). On the other hand it is essentially undocumented (unless you buy the book by Skiena and Pemmaraju) and the quality of Mathematica programming is not great (there are also bugs that never seem to get fixed).

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. The difference of the commands between Combinatorica and Mathematica still confuses me.

Comment: @NicYoung Maybe it's also useful to know that you can convert a new style graph to a Combinatorica graph using the `ToCombinatoricaGraph` function of the ``GraphUtilities` `` package.

Answer (score 2):

Without using the `Combinatorica` package, you can use

```
 Table[{i, GraphData[{"Cycle", i}, "SpanningTreeCount"] == i}, 
{i, 3, 20}] // TableForm
```

to get

```
 {{3, True}, {4, True}, {5, True}, {6, True}, {7, True}, {8, True}, 
 {9, True}, {10, True}, {11, True}, {12, True}, {13, True}, {14, True}, 
 {15, True}, {16, True}, {17, True}, {18, True}, {19, True}, {20, True}}
```

This does not work for `i>20` since `GraphData` contains named cycle graphs `{"Cycle", i}` for `i<=20.`

Answer (score 1):

`NumberOfSpanningTrees` is a Combinatorica package function. `CycleGraph` is part of the built-in [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) framework. Combinatorica and the built-in `Graph` are distinct and incompatible.

[The IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now includes a function to count spanning trees, `IGSpanningTreeCount`.  IGraph/M is designed to be compatible with and complement the built-in `Graph` functionality.

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[CycleGraph[3]]
(* 3 *)
```

This function also works with multigraphs and directed graphs.

Count the spanning trees of a directed 3-cycle:

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[CycleGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True]]
(* 3 *)
```

Count the spanning trees that are rooted in vertex 1.

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[CycleGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True], 1]
(* 1 *)
```

A non-strongly-connected directed graph has no spanning trees.

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2}]]
(* 0 *)
```

With these extensions, `IGSpanningTreeCount` is more flexible than what Combinatorica includes.